# How can I access the query parameters from a custom authorizer in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am attempting to implement a custom authorizer for my websocket API, which depends on the query parameters.

Based on [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-lambda-auth.html), it seems like this should be possible like so:

```
export const handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

   // A simple REQUEST authorizer example to demonstrate how to use request 
   // parameters to allow or deny a request. In this example, a request is  
   // authorized if the client-supplied HeaderAuth1 header and QueryString1 query parameter
   // in the request context match the specified values of
   // of 'headerValue1' and 'queryValue1' respectively.

   // Retrieve request parameters from the Lambda function input:
   var headers = event.headers;
   var queryStringParameters = event.queryStringParameters;
   ...
```

I am trying to implement similar in typescript, but I cannot figure out which types are needed to get access to the query parameters.  When I try to use `APIGatewayTokenAuthorizerEvent`, the field `queryStringParameters` does not exist.

In the above example, what would be the type of `event`, `context`, and `callback` in the typescript context?

Comment: How about `APIGatewayAuthorizerEvent` or `APIGatewayRequestAuthorizerEvent`? It's generally better to implement the handler itself like `export const handler : APIGatewayAuthorizerHandler = ...` which will allow TS to typecheck it in its entirety